# What happens to SQL statements before any SQL statement throws exception?

Tags: flyway

What happens to SQL statements before any SQL statement throws exception? I am using Flyway DB 3.0 with Oracle SqlPlus execution.

I want to understand what happens if I have 100 SQL statements and an exception is thrown at 70th SQL statement : Will all previous 69 SQL statements will be rolled back?

Answer (score 0):

This is described in detail in the FAQ: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#rollback